# Loading Segments of Data with AngularJS Service

Tags: angularjs, service, get, load

I have a get request which is fetching comments from an article.
For optimization, I wanted to load the first 25, and continuously load additional sets of 25 on each click of "load more".

I currently have the following (params passed is the article ID) --

```
ArticleService.get(params).then(function(data) {
  $scope.comments = data.comments;
});
```

What's the best way to adjust the get request to load 25 at a time on an ng-click set on a button?

Comment: whats is in your backend?

Comment: Rails. There is a Rails controller with the following -- 
def comments
    comments = []
    article = Community.find params[:id]
    article.children.where(status: 'active').order('total_likes DESC, id ASC').each do |comment|
      comments << Community.parse_article(current_user, comment)
    end

    render json: { comments: comments }
  end

Comment: I don't know Rails, but there should be some kind on .skip() function you can use like so: where(status: 'active').order('total_likes DESC, id ASC').skip(loaded_already). Then you can set on your request params a variable: loaded_already = $scope.comments.length. Make sense?. Also note that if you say $scope.comments = data.comments on request success, the comments will be overridden, you will need to push to the array instead

Comment: I forgot, you will also send how many you want back on each request (25).  something like this you can use: .limit(25).offset(loaded_already)

Comment: this is great! thanks so much for the point in the right direction. .slide(index, 25).each in Rails did the trick

Comment: Anytime..Glad it helped you!